# Match elements of an array from a JSON Array of Objects using Chai

Tags: javascript, chai, assertions, chakram

Let's say I have an array

```
let array_of_string = ['John','Jack','Smith','Ryan'];
```

How can I assert that these keys are included in JSON array of objects where the JSON is something like this

```
[ {
    "person_name": "Jake",
    "person_id": '1234',
    "employee_type": "Regular"
}, {
    "person_name": "Adam",
    "person_id": '1245',
    "employee_type": "Contractor"
}, {
    "person_name": "John",
    "person_id": '2342',
    "employee_type": "Regular"
}, {
    "person_name": "Smith",
    "person_id": '3456',
    "employee_type": "Contractor"
}, {
    "person_name": "Ryan",
    "person_id": '0123',
    "employee_type": "Regular"
} ]
```

I am using `Chai` to have the assertions. Using `include` and `deep.Equal` doesn't seem to work.

The JSON Array is response of an API. So currently I tried this

```
it('checks if the elements are in API response', () => {
  return response.then(function(resp){
    expect(resp).to.be.an('array').that.includes(array_of_string )
  })
})
```

Comment: you just want to check if all the values of `array_of_string` exist in that map ? right ?

Comment: yeah. That would be it. Should I use `map`.

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49878890/6804958) answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed "Jack" to "Jake" in the list of names and removed "Adam" from the response data to ensure that every name appeared in the data to prove the function's use below.

The JS Doc preceding the function describes what it does.

```js
/*
 * Check if each value exist (at least once) in a list (by its key).
 * @param {object[]} list - List of objects.
 * @param {string[]} vals - List of values to search for.
 * @param {string}   key  - Key for each object to check the value.
 * @return {boolean} Returns wheteher all values exist in the list.
 */
const fn = (list, vals, key) => vals.every(val => list.some(e => e[key] === val));

var names = [ 'Jake', 'John', 'Smith', 'Ryan' ];
var responseData = [{
  "person_name": "Jake",
  "person_id": '1234',
  "employee_type": "Regular"
}, {
  "person_name": "John",
  "person_id": '2342',
  "employee_type": "Regular"
}, {
  "person_name": "Smith",
  "person_id": '3456',
  "employee_type": "Contractor"
}, {
  "person_name": "Ryan",
  "person_id": '0123',
  "employee_type": "Regular"
}];

// names.every(name => responseData.some(p => p['person_name'] === name));
console.log('All names present?', fn(responseData, names, 'person_name'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Smooth. Thanks. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how I would have done it. And This is in plain `JS`

```js
'use strict';

var array_of_string = ['John', 'Jack', 'Smith', 'Ryan', 'Usman'];
var list = [{
    "person_name": "Jake",
    "person_id": '1234',
    "employee_type": "Regular"
}, {
    "person_name": "Adam",
    "person_id": '1245',
    "employee_type": "Contractor"
}, {
    "person_name": "John",
    "person_id": '2342',
    "employee_type": "Regular"
}, {
    "person_name": "Smith",
    "person_id": '3456',
    "employee_type": "Contractor"
}, {
    "person_name": "Ryan",
    "person_id": '0123',
    "employee_type": "Regular"
}];
var b = true;
array_of_string.forEach(function (name) {

    if (list.some(e=>e.person_name === name)) {} else {
        b = false;
        return false;
    }
});

console.log(b);
```

If all the elements of `array_of_string` exists as `person_name` property in that, this should log `true` else `false`.

Comment: Couldn't you use `Array.prototype.every` or `Array.prototype.some`?

Comment: sure, I could do that.  thanks for mentioning. I almost skipped `Array.prototype.some` when writing answer `:p`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use Chai assertion on Chakram response.

```
 const namesArray = [];
 resp.map(person => namesArray.push(person.person_name));
 names.every(name => expect(namesArray).to.include(name));
});
```